# node.js: jest unit tests: do mocks need to be drained?

Tags: node.js, jest-fetch-mock

At [https://github.com/rancher-sandbox/rancher-desktop/blob/22f94cb2c3a8cd0734f2f4f505b10ee660e94041/pkg/rancher-desktop/backend/**tests**/k3sHelper.spec.ts#L194](https://github.com/rancher-sandbox/rancher-desktop/blob/22f94cb2c3a8cd0734f2f4f505b10ee660e94041/pkg/rancher-desktop/backend/__tests__/k3sHelper.spec.ts#L194) we have a sequence of mocks for `fetch`, structured like so:

```
jest.mocked(fetch).mockImplementationOnce((url) => {
// Fake fetching from a channel
}).mockImplementationOnce((url) => {
// Fake fetching release data
}).mockImplementationOnce((url) => {
// Fake hitting a 403
}).mockImplementationOnce((url) => {
// Fake getting the end of the data
}).mockImplementationOnce((url) => {
  // Shouldn't call this one!
  throw new Error(`Unexpected fetch call to ${ url }`);
});
// Do the thing ...
expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(4);
```

I added a new test, that runs immediately after the one I described,
with its own sequence of mocked fetches.
But the first call to `fetch` hits the fifth mocked function in the
previous test.

We have a `beforeEach` that we think clears the mocked fetch:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.mocked(fetch).mockClear();
});
```

If I add a fifth call to `try { fetch('blah') } catch{}` in the first test, the second test runs as expected.

Currently the first test is the only test where `fetch` is getting mocked.

So my question is, do we still need to ensure that all the mocked calls are actually hit before trying to write a new test that also mocks `fetch`? The docs at https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api only say what happens if you call a mocked function too many times, but there's no mention of what happens when you don't consume all the mocked implementations.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change the call to `mockClear` to in that `beforeEach` to `mockReset`. I'm dense, because the docs for `mockReset` say:

```
Does everything that mockFn.mockClear() does, and also replaces the mock implementation with an empty function, returning undefined.
```

I suppose if I write 10,000 more jest tests one day I'll understand why I would not want `mockClear` to clear the unused function mocks. But todaay I'm baffled....